# Django Rest API from Database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have 2 APIs from my existing project. Where One provides the latest blog posts and another one provides sorting details. The 2nd API (sorting) gives blog posts ID and an ordering number, which should be in the 1st,2nd,3rd...n position. If I filter in the first API with that given ID I can get the blog post details.

How can I create a Django REST API from Database? or an API merging from that 2 APIs? Any tutorial or reference which might help me?

Frist API Response:

```
{
  "count": 74,
  "next": "https://cms.example.com/api/v2/stories/?page=2",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 111,
      "meta": {
        "type": "blog.CreateStory",
        "seo_title": "",
        "search_description": "",
        "first_published_at": "2022-10-09T07:29:17.029746Z"
      },
      "title": "A Test Blog Post"
},
{
      "id": 105,
      "meta": {
        "type": "blog.CreateStory",
        "seo_title": "",
        "search_description": "",
        "first_published_at": "2022-10-08T04:45:32.165072Z"
      },
      "title": "Blog Story 2"
},
```

2nd API Response

```
[
  {
    "featured_item": 1,
    "sort_order": 0,
    "featured_page": 105
  },
  {
    "featured_item": 1,
    "sort_order": 1,
    "featured_page": 90
  },
```

Here I want to create another API that will provide more details about sorting for example it will sort like this `https://cms.example.com/api/v2/stories/105` and catch `Title, Image & Excerpt` and If there is no data from Sorting details it will show the first API's response by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I found that you can make API from Database. In setting you need to set the database credentials and then need to create a class inside your `models.py` and inside class's meta you need to set meta name to `db_table` and then create `serializers.py` and `views.py` as you create REST API.

```
class SortAPI(models.Model):
    featured_item_id = models.IntegerField()
    sort_order = models.IntegerField()
    title=models.TextField()
    first_published_at=models.DateTimeField()
    alternative_title= models.TextField()
    excerpt=models.TextField()
    sub_heading=models.TextField()
    news_slug=models.TextField()
    img_title=models.TextField()
    img_url=models.TextField()
    img_width=models.IntegerField()
    img_height=models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'view_featured'
```